# How to not increment table versions in Glue when adding new Partitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

When adding new partitions into a table in Glue, I'm observing the versionId number of the table is increasing.

Since the number of versions per table is a limit in AWS(up to 100.000), I would like to control the situation by not removing versions using a script, instead, It would be great to have a behaviour like setting the table to not increment the version sequentially every time a new partition is added.

**Is It possible to set a behaviour like that in AWS Glue?**
Even, set a fixed table version number for each partition would be great.

Note: I do not want to simply change the AWS limit, I mean, I want a permanent solution to this problem.